# Flying Bike: Pilot Masks

Tags: flight, transportation, sports

In the same vein as [my other question about flying bikes,](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/33824/14837) I want the bike pilots to wear high-tech customized masks which give them important details about their situation as a HUD type thing. What sort of details would be useful? I've already thought of things like speed, altitude, and wind heading and speed. Also, what other features could the masks have that might come in handy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In real life the Jet Fighter pilots already have this helmets or similar devices to display info for them - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display.

I'll cite wikipedia here:

Typical aircraft HUDs display airspeed, altitude, a horizon line, heading, turn/bank and slip/skid indicators. These instruments are the minimum required by 14 CFR Part 91.[12]

Other symbols and data are also available in some HUDs:

- boresight or waterline symbol—is fixed on the display and shows where the nose of the aircraft is actually pointing.
- flight path vector (FPV) or velocity vector symbol—shows where the aircraft is actually going, the sum of all forces acting on the aircraft.[13] For example, if the aircraft is pitched up but is losing energy, then the FPV symbol will be below the horizon even though the boresight symbol is above the horizon. During approach and landing, a pilot can fly the approach by keeping the FPV symbol at the desired descent angle and touchdown point on the runway.
- acceleration indicator or energy cue—typically to the left of the FPV symbol, it is above it if the aircraft is accelerating, and below the FPV symbol if decelerating.
- angle of attack indicator—shows the wing's angle relative to the airflow, often displayed as "α".
- navigation data and symbols—for approaches and landings, the flight guidance systems can provide visual cues based on navigation aids such as an Instrument Landing System or augmented Global Positioning System such as the Wide Area Augmentation System. Typically this is a circle which fits inside the flight path vector symbol. Pilots can fly along the correct flight path by "flying to" the guidance cue.

Since being introduced on HUDs, both the FPV and acceleration symbols are becoming standard on head-down displays (HDD). The actual form of the FPV symbol on an HDD is not standardized but is usually a simple aircraft drawing, such as a circle with two short angled lines, (180 ± 30 degrees) and "wings" on the ends of the descending line. Keeping the FPV on the horizon allows the pilot to fly level turns in various angles of bank.
Military aircraft specific applications
FA-18 HUD while engaged in a mock dogfight

In addition to the generic information described above, military applications include weapons system and sensor data such as:

- target designation (TD) indicator—places a cue over an air or ground target (which is typically derived from radar or inertial navigation system data).
- Vc—closing velocity with target.
- Range—to target, waypoint, etc.
- weapon seeker or sensor line of sight—shows where a seeker or sensor is pointing.
- weapon status—includes type and number of weapons selected, available, arming, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You would need speed, altitude, velocity towards ground, pockets of high/low pressure air, the possibility of infrared, radar, fuel, wind speed and heading, status updates about the bike, and visual enhancement for night-time flying.

Here's some potential disasters without each of those things:

No altitude meter: KABOOM!

No velocity-towards-ground meter: You would lose track of your accleration due to gravity and, again, go KABOOM!

Pockets of low/high pressure air: "Ladies and gentlemen, we may be expecting some turbulence. Some potential dangers include: the pilot losing control, the pilot falling off, or general quick and painful death."

No infrared: If you're at night, then a bird might smack you in the face, or something like that. Not essential, if your regular vision is good enough, but would still be enough.

No radar: You would almost certainly crash into something.

No fuel meter: Putter...Putter...KABOOM!

No wind speed: It would be difficult to control the bike as well as anticipate gales of wind.

No status updates: Your motor falling off in the middle of the flight might be a bad thing...

No night-time visual enhancment: You might as well be flying blindfolded at that point.

In short: Unless you have all those things, KABOOM!